# EBS full device confusion

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mount, amazon-ebs

I have a 500GB EBS device (/dev/xvdf) mounted to /vol and all data on the box seems to be writing to /vol correctly (see du output below). For some reason /dev/xvda1 is totally full.

Any idea what's going on here?

$ df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       32G   30G  8.0K 100% /
udev             34G  8.0K   34G   1% /dev
tmpfs            14G  176K   14G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             34G     0   34G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       827G  201M  785G   1% /mnt
/dev/xvdf       500G  145G  356G  29% /vol
```

$ du -sh *

```
8.7M  bin
18M   boot
8.0K  dev
5.1M  etc
48K   home
0     initrd.img
80M   lib
4.0K  lib64
16K   lost+found
4.0K  media
20K   mnt
4.0K  opt
0     proc
40K   root
176K  run
7.1M  sbin
4.0K  selinux
4.0K  srv
0     sys
4.0K  tmp
414M  usr
356M  var
0     vmlinuz
145G  vol
```

Comment: If you umount /vol is there any content in the underlying /vol ?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be related but when I had a similar issue with the root filesystem being nearly full but the usual du commands wasn't revealing the source I eventually discovered it was a mongodb log file which was many GBs in size but not showing up properly because the file was open at the time or something.

Comment: Yeah, did you delete any big log files without restarting the daemon that created them? If a process has an open file handle, doesn't matter if the file is deleted, the space will only be recouped once the process releases the file handle.